# Pagination in perl script

Tags: html, perl

I have a perl script which reads a text file contents into a variable. The script displays the contents on a web page using html. Is there anyway to create pagination for the data displayed?

TIA

Answer (score 5):

Pagination is a pretty well-understood problem. Your solution will almost certainly be simpler if you use [Data::Page](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Page).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this site for CSS and HTML pagination examples](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-pagination-styles). It is up to you how you display it from the perl, but it could be a start.